# Binding to a parent's context in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

I just can't get my head around it. My brain melts trying to understand how to bind to a parent's context.

So here I have a (relatively) simple object:

```
public class BinDefinition
{
public string labelAdresse { get; set; }
public InventoryItem inventoryItem { get; set; }
public List<BinContent> binContents { get; set; }
public List<InventoryProduct> productsinBinContent { get; set; }
public bool showDeleteButton { get; set; }
public bool showTransferButton { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then I have my view model that has two of these bindefinitions.

```
public class viewModel
{
public binDefinition primaryBin { get; set; }
public binDefinition secondaryBin { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, the relevant xaml part:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" Grid.Row="1" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                ItemTapped="ItemsListView_ItemTapped"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding EANReference}"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding QuantityDisplay}"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="DarkBlue" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                <Button Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Info" Clicked="btnInfos_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding EAN}"/>
                                <Button Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="Del" Clicked="btnDel_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.primaryBin.showDeleteButton, Source={x:Reference Inv2PageMainContent}}"/>
                                <Button Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="Tra" Clicked="btnTransfer_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.primaryBin.showTransferButton, Source={x:Reference Inv2PageMainContent}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I am trying to bind the two final button so that the show up or hide depending on the state of the boolean available in BinDefinition. But at that point, the datacontext of said button is a ListItem (from the Items in the viewModel).
I just don't know how to call back the direct parent to use its property.

edit: apologies, it seems I failed to provide sufficient informations.

the inv2MainpageContent is the name of the page. x:Name = inv2MainPageContent.

The BindingContext of the page is an instance of the viewModel. That viewModel contain two binDefinitions. And in that bin Definition are multiple properties. The three that are important to me are the bool ShowDelete/ShowTransfer and the Collection  Items.

The List view in my view has dug into the primaryBin and uses "primaryBin.Items" as its ItemSource. The thing is, I would like to bind the visibility of these objects to the the primaryBin.ShowDelete/ShowTransfer.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "how to call back the direct parent to use its property"? You've not really made clear what your structure is. That said in general I think if you want to bind to a path (so a property on a property) you have to do so like this: `IsVisible="{Binding Path=BindingContext.primaryBin.showDeleteButton, Source={x:Reference Inv2PageMainContent}}"`. Depending on what you actually want to achieve that might fix your problem

Comment: Where the reference `Inv2PageMainContent` is defined ? Where are you setting the `BindingContext` ? Personally speaking the relation between your 2 classes and xaml is not clear to me from the question.

Comment: To set binding to the parent's context, you could add `x:Name` for the parent's parent layout. Then set binding for the `BindingContext` using `x:Reference`. Check the code: `<ContentPage ... x:Name="page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding models}" ...>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                ...
                   <Button Text="{Binding BtnText}" BindingContext="{x:Reference page}"/>
                ...
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>`.